# Remove stopwords from tokenizaton

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

I having problem to remove stopwords from tokenization. I have already tokenized sentences and insert the result with pandas to the column named "tweets_tokenize". The problem is I have double bracket ( [ ] ), the result only one and repeated (details see image) and the stopwords didn't work if using first function. But, if using second function is good. Can explain why?

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords_indonesia = stopwords.words('indonesian')

# First function
def stopwords_remover(words):
    words = df['tweets_tokenize']
    tweets_stopwords = []
    for word in words:
        if word not in stopwords_indonesia:
            tweets_stopwords.append(word)
    return tweets_stopwords

# Second function
def stopwords_remover(words):
    tweets_stopwords = []
    for word in words:
        if word not in stopwords_indonesia:
            tweets_stopwords.append(word)
    return tweets_stopwords

df['tweets_tokenize'].apply(stopwords_remover)
df.head()
```

Result using first function.

[image: First function]

Result using second function.

[image: Second function]

Comment: is this the full code? do you declare somewhere in the code the variable tweets_stopwords as global variable?

Comment: Sorry I'm giving the wrong code.

Comment: saw the correction, please find my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The First Function:**

The reason is the line:

```
words = df['tweets_tokenize']
```

The type of the object is 'pandas.core.series.Series' and once you iterate it in the loop, the object word will be type of list.

When you are appending it in this line:

```
tweets_stopwords.append(word)
```

You are actually appending a list, and not a word. This is why you have a lists wrapped with a big list.

**The second function:**

iterates each row separately, and the object type is a regular string.

**Summary:**

When you use apply function of pandas, it will be a better use to handle it row by row like the second function, without using the entire column as mentioned in the first function.

Comment: Thanks for the explantion. It helped me. And I have one more question for second function. Where `words` gets data before inserting to `word`? If I don't declare variable like `words = df['tweets_tokenize']`

Comment: the function apply of pandas iterates behind the scene on each row of the column you asked, and sends the value of the row into the function. in your example, for each value in the column 'tweets_tokenize' in sends the list of the tokens

Comment: Ah, I see. You very helped me.